# css responsive menu drop down width

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to adapt a responsive menu to work on my site. I've attached a jsfiddle of my progress so far:

[jsfiddle of my progress](http://jsfiddle.net/tonmachine100/6ZmeC/9/)

Menu list items 2 and 3 have drop down menus which appear when hovered over:

1. If the screen width is over 20em the drop downs will float over (hide) the page content.
2. If the page width is under 20em the drop downs force the page content down so the menus do not hide the content.

This all works OK, however in scenario b) i need the drop down menu width to be 100% of the page width (if the page content is under 20em). You'll notice that when you hover over items 2 and 3 (when the page width is under 20em) the menus are narrow. How can they be made to 100% page width?

i presume some changes need to be made to the media query:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 20em) /* 320 */ {}`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but I've used this on my site and it stays the same width no matter what the browser window size is, of course mine isn't a drop down bar, so I can't guarantee that the drop-downs will stay the same width (they should)

Here's what I've done, I've created a div for my menu and placed the menu inside the div like so.

```
<div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="special-offers.php">Special Offers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Partners-&-Affiliates.php">Partners & Affiliates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

You can edit code so that it's the same as yours.

and here is the css for the menu (again you can edit it to make it like yours)

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: darkgoldenrod;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;  
}

#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0; 
}

#nav li {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
}

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; 
}

#nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc; 
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: peru; 
}
```

I hope that this helps.